# Make Gtk.TreeView display calculated cell content

Tags: python, treeview, gtk

In Python, using Gtk 3.0, I have a `ListStore` conatining an `int` column.  I do *not* want to change the `ListStore`, but I want the shown cell content to be *derived* from the stored value, by using SI suffixes (i.e., display 1.3k instead of the 1300 from the `ListStore`).

The following MWE is based on [this example](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578772-basic-gtktreeview-example-with-two-sortable-column/).  That example, however, calculates a third column and adds it to the underlying `ListStore`.  Then the original data is simply not shown in the view.  I do not want to do that (I think it does not scale well with adding different views or formatting functions).

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

import os, math



def siSize(x): # simplified version
    if x > 1000:
        return '{:.1f}k'.format(x / 1000)
    else:
        return str(x)


class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):

        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)

        self.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)


        store = Gtk.ListStore(str, int)
        #store = Gtk.ListStore(str, str)

        for name in os.listdir('.'):
            size = os.path.getsize(name)
            store.append([name, size])
            #store.append([name, siSize(size)])       

        col1 = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('Name', Gtk.CellRendererText(), text=0)
        col1.set_sort_column_id(0)        

        col2 = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('Size', Gtk.CellRendererText(), text=1)
        col2.set_sort_column_id(2)

        treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=store)
        treeview.append_column(col1)
        treeview.append_column(col2)        

        scroll = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scroll.set_policy(Gtk.PolicyType.NEVER, Gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC)
        scroll.set_min_content_height(200)
        scroll.add(treeview)

        self.add(scroll)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

I have tried to utilise `set_cell_data_func`, but to no avail.  I have not found sufficient documentation on that, only [this one](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtktreeviewcolumn.html#method-gtktreeviewcolumn--set-cell-data-func).

I have tried to subclass my own `CellRendererSize` from `Gtk.CellRendererText`, but have failed to find documentation about what I'd need to implement, and how it would be used.

Comment: Why do you think it's better to format data everytime it's drawn instead of formatting it when it changes?

Comment: IMHO it feels like a cleaner design to have the rendering details not in the underlying model.  Dynamically adding different views would require to change the model, which then must be made careful to not disturb precalculated values added in order to serve other views.  Also, I assume that the complexity of the actual GUI rendering completely dwarfs the complexity of recalculating the content to be shown.

Comment: Great. If you expect that one model will be rendered in different ways, then you can make a set of widgets, which expect some standardized model as input and then rewrite it to own internal model with necessary fields for rendering text. Moreover, you assumption (which I agree to) confirms this point: there is no need to recalculate content at every render event, if you can calculate it only once.

Comment: To make things clear: I don't know, how to interrupt the rendering process and change some text to other. And as far as I know, it's not possible. But again: I think, it's OK to calculate once and render 100 times, than calculate every single time

Comment: I was interested in this also, for memory saving reasons. a very large data store, i'd just store the date as a number, but display it as a formatted string (which would take way more memory). As it is, it seems I must actually store the formatted string in memory for all the rows in the grid.

Comment: So, a custom cell renderer would allow to achieve this for sure but it seems massively overkill.